# Possible type refining bug in typescript for string property in class

Tags: typescript

Here is my simplest example to reproduce:

```
class Game {
    phase: "draw" | "action";

    constructor() {
        this.phase = "draw";
    }

    randomChangePhase() {
        if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
            this.phase = "action";
        } else {
            this.phase = "draw";
        }
    }

    doTurn(){
        if(this.phase !== "draw") {
            throw new Error(`cannot call doTurn in phase ${this.phase}`);
        }

        this.randomChangePhase();

        while(this.phase !== "action") {
            this.randomChangePhase();
        }

        console.log(this.phase);
    }
}
```

Using tsc version Version 3.7.5, I see this error:

> typescript/test.ts:24:15 - error TS2367: This condition will always
>   return 'true' since the types '"draw"' and '"action"' have no overlap.
>
> 24         while(this.phase !== "action") {
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Found 1 error.

Can you folks confirm my understanding that this is in fact a bug?

If so, any idea if this is a known bug, or if there is a way to fix this in config?

EDIT: apologies, the code was missing the crucial portion.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to call it a bug, it has been consciously made to work this way, it is relatively reasonable to want it to act like this to make these discriminated unions a practical thing. Indeed otherwise in these discriminated unions you would be liable to lose all the inferred information as soon as you call a function, so it's a tradeoff. There's a lengthy discussion about it here. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: Apologies, I was missing the key component. Code is now fixed to reflect the nature of the bug

Comment: @Countingstuff as you mentioned, the discussion in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998 seems relevant. They have the same testcase of non-deterministically changing an instance property using a method and finding that the type refinement is incorrect. Would it be possible for you to summarize that discussion, then I can accept that as the answer.